# why this in a callback causes the code to stop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, callback, leaderboard

After recovering my data with Firebase using a callback in GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task..) , I would like to instantiate my prefab in order to see the list of scores for my leaderboard. But, it does nothing and I have no errors. The code simply stops in the callback UseSores as soon as it come across on a 'this' or a 'instantiate'.

```
public class Leaderboardmanager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject rowLeardBoard;
    FirebaseDB_Read read;
    float positionX; 
    int nbRows = 10;

    void Start()
    {   
        read = (gameObject.AddComponent<FirebaseDB_Read>());
        GetScorePlayer();
    } 

    void GetScorePlayer()
    {
        read.GetScores(UseScores, "entries/LeaderBoard/", nbRows);
    }

    void UseScores(IList<FirebaseDB_Read.Score> scores)
    {
        Debug.Log("arrive here");
        positionX = this.transform.position.y; 
        Debug.Log("does not arrive here");
    }
}
```

Here is to get my data :

```
public class FirebaseDB_Read : MonoBehaviour
{

    public class Score
    {
        public string UID;
        public string score;
        public int rank;
    }


    public void GetScores(Action<IList<Score>> callback, string URL_TO_SCORES, int limit)
    {
        DatabaseReference scoresRef = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference(URL_TO_SCORES);

        scoresRef.OrderByChild("score").LimitToLast(limit).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
            IList<Score> objectsList = new List<Score> { };

            int i = 1;
            foreach (var childSnapshot in snapshot.Children)
            {
                Score score = new Score();
                score.rank = i;
                score.UID = childSnapshot.Child("UID").GetValue(true).ToString();
                score.score = childSnapshot.Child("score").GetValue(true).ToString();

                objectsList.Add(score);
                i++;
            }

            callback(objectsList);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an often asked problem in Unity: Because you `ContinueWith` on a **background thread**!

Unity isn't thread-safe, meaning that most of the Unity API can only be used within the Unity main thread.

Firebase offers an extension specifically for Unity: [`ContinueWithOnMainThread`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension) which assures that the result is handled in the Unity main thread where accessing the API is valid.

```
scoresRef.OrderByChild("score").LimitToLast(limit).GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
{
    ...
});
```

---

As alternative you can use kind of a so called "main thread dispatcher" pattern and make sure that the `callback` is executed in the main thread on the receiver side. The advantage of this would be that the still expensive operations on your list are all executed on a background thread, not affecting the UI performance

```
scoresRef.OrderByChild("score").LimitToLast(limit).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
{
    ...
});
```

but then on receiver side in `FirebaseDB_Read`

```
private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Action> _mainThreadActions = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();

private void Update()
{
    if(_mainThreadAction.Count > 0)
    {
        while(_mainThreadActions.TryDequeue(out var action))
        {
            action?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}

void GetScorePlayer()
{
    read.GetScores(UseScores, "entries/LeaderBoard/", nbRows);
}

void UseScores(IList<FirebaseDB_Read.Score> scores)
{
    // handle this in the next main thread update
    _mainThreadActions.Enqueue(() =>
    {
        Debug.Log("arrive here");
        positionX = this.transform.position.y; 
        Debug.Log("does not arrive here");
    }
}
```

which on the offside of course introduces a little overhead for checking for any new actions in `Update` of course. So if you plan do use multiple of such background actions make sure to implement them in one central place in order to keep the overhead limited ;)

Comment: @Vanz glad to help! Please feel free to accept the answer ;)